# Block requests containing substring

Tags: regex, nginx

I want to block requests to the WordPress search like this containing one or multiple times `%20` with nginx because those are from bots and slowing down the server extremely:

```
/?s=Inuyasha%20Toki%20o%20Koeru%20Omoi
```

I tried this:

```
if ($args ~ ^s=*%20*$) { return 404; }
```

But it does not work. I'm not very familiar with nginx regex.

How would it be correct?

Comment: Are you developing a proxy sort of application?

Comment: no i want to block such requests to nginx in the nginx vhost config file

Comment: If it does normal regex, it would be `%20` What you have there doesn't do what you think it will. If you want to have literal validation it would be `s=Inuyasha(%20.*?){1,max}`

Answer (score 1):

Nginx maps every request parameter to a variable, like "s=" - $arg_s, "foo=" - $arg_foo

so
if ($arg_s ~ ...

you get the point

Comment: ok. i tried if ($arg_s ~ ^*%20*$) { return 404; } but its not working

Comment: but this finally works: if ($arg_s ~ %20) { return 404; } 
thanks  for help with the parameter